# Having some trouble creating a C money calculator

Tags: c

I am trying to create a money calculator programmed in C. The calculator gets data from stdin. This is the expected result I want:

```
$ ./alkansiya
Welcome to the Alkansiya Calculator!
How many 1000 pesos?
3
How many 500 pesos?
7
How many 200 pesos?
0
How many 100 pesos?
15
How many 50 pesos?
23
How many 20 pesos?
46
How many 10 pesos?
162
How many 5 pesos?
279
How many 1 pesos?
73
How many 50 cents?
4
How many 25 cents?
1
How many 10 cents?
0
How many 5 cents?
0
How many 1 cents?
0
Your balance is 13158 pesos and 225 centavos
```

However, my code below is not the same as the expected result, which ends up with a segmentation fault:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int onethousandpesos = 0;
    int fivehundredpesos = 0;
    int twohundredpesos = 0;
    int onehundredpesos = 0;
    int fiftypesos = 0;
    int twentypesos = 0;
    int tenpesos = 0;
    int fivepesos = 0;
    int onepeso = 0;
    int fiftycentavos = 0;
    int twentyfivecentavos = 0;
    int tencentavos = 0;
    int fivecentavos = 0;
    int onecentavo = 0;

    printf("Welcome to the Alkansiya Calculator!\n");
    printf("How many 1000 pesos?\n");
        scanf("%i", onethousandpesos);
    printf("How many 500 pesos?\n");
        scanf("%i", fivehundredpesos);
    printf("How many 200 pesos?\n");
        scanf("%i", twohundredpesos);
    printf("How many 100 pesos?\n");
        scanf("%i", onehundredpesos);
    printf("How many 50 pesos?\n");
        scanf("%i", fiftypesos);
    printf("How many 20 pesos?\n");
        scanf("%i", twentypesos);
    printf("How many 10 pesos?\n");
        scanf("%i", tenpesos);
    printf("How many 5 pesos?\n");
        scanf("%i", fivepesos);
    printf("How many 1 pesos?\n");
        scanf("%i", onepeso);
    printf("How many 50 cents?\n");
        scanf("%i", fiftycentavos);
    printf("How many 25 cents?\n");
        scanf("%i", twentyfivecentavos);
    printf("How many 10 cents?\n");
        scanf("%i", tencentavos);
    printf("How many 5 cents?\n");
        scanf("%i", fivecentavos);
    printf("How many 1 cents?\n");
        scanf("%i", onecentavo);
    printf("Your balance is %i pesos ", (1000*onethousandpesos)+(500*fivehundredpesos)+(200*twohundredpesos)+(100*onehundredpesos)+(50*fiftypesos)+(20*twentypesos)+(10*tenpesos)+(5*fivepesos)+onepeso);
    printf("and '''%d''' centavos.\n", fiftycentavos+twentyfivecentavos+tencentavos+fivecentavos+onecentavo);

    return 0;
}
```

GCC 7.3.0 returns these warnings:

```
alkansiya.c: In function ‘main’:
alkansiya.c:21:11: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
   scanf("%i", onethousandpesos);
          ~^
alkansiya.c:23:11: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
   scanf("%i", fivehundredpesos);
          ~^
alkansiya.c:25:11: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
   scanf("%i", twohundredpesos);
          ~^
alkansiya.c:27:11: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
   scanf("%i", onehundredpesos);
          ~^
alkansiya.c:29:11: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
   scanf("%i", fiftypesos);
          ~^
alkansiya.c:31:11: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
   scanf("%i", twentypesos);
          ~^
alkansiya.c:33:11: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
   scanf("%i", tenpesos);
          ~^
alkansiya.c:35:11: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
   scanf("%i", fivepesos);
          ~^
alkansiya.c:37:11: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
   scanf("%i", onepeso);
          ~^
alkansiya.c:39:11: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
   scanf("%i", fiftycentavos);
          ~^
alkansiya.c:41:11: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
   scanf("%i", twentyfivecentavos);
          ~^
alkansiya.c:43:11: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
   scanf("%i", tencentavos);
          ~^
alkansiya.c:45:11: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
   scanf("%i", fivecentavos);
          ~^
alkansiya.c:47:11: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
   scanf("%i", onecentavo);
```

I don't understand these warnings. I tried to fix it, but still no luck. I am a beginner in C. Can someone help me fix this code?

Comment: `scanf("%i", foo)` -> `scanf("%i", &foo)`

Comment: Read those warnings, they tell you exactly what's wrong. And go back to your text book and start over from the beginning.

Comment: @PaulR Perfect! My calculator works without problems. Please post it as an answer so that I can accept it :)

Comment: `scanf` `%i` is not recommended. I suggest `%d` instead (actually, I'd suggest not using `scanf` at all for user input).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am going to put that in my mind always while learning C. Well atleast I have learned something important from this :)

Comment: Glad to hear it works - no need for an answer though as this is a common problem and there are most likely quite a few duplicate questions already (I’m feeling to lazy to go and look for them just now).

Comment: @Paul Please name one. Nobody has yet found one.

Comment: @melpomene Yes, I have heard it while I am starting in writing my calculator. I am going to use this calculator personally anyway, so I don't need to worry about buffer overflows, but thanks for the tip anyway :)

Comment: I'm not talking about buffer overflows.

Comment: @Yunnosch: Here’s [one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3135946/253056)...

Comment: @PaulR Perfect; is now part of my "dupe menue"... ;-)

Comment: @melpomene In https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Simple_Input_and_Output#Input_using_scanf(), after providing examples and correct usage of scanf, the book then didn't recommend using scanf for input: "(Although, this is vulnerable to Buffer overflow. fgets() is preferred to scanf())."

Comment: @temy That paragraph is talking about `%s`.

Comment: @melpomene Ok, it seems I have misunderstood.

Answer (score -1):

Bugs:

1. Whenever you take any input from the stdin you have take &(a person) this address operator for storage the data into any variable in `scanf` function thus was a bug which create the segmentation fault
2. When you take any signed integer input you have to use the 
   `%d` in place of `%i` this was a bug which causes the Warning

I have taken your program and compiled and removed the bugs and below there is a program which is error free. You can just copy and paste into editor and check the output 
 And reply me if any problem I will help you out

Note: before checking output please observe the modification with ur old file current below code

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main(void) {
    int onethousandpesos = 0;
    int fivehundredpesos = 0;
    int twohundredpesos = 0;
    int onehundredpesos = 0;
    int fiftypesos = 0;
    int twentypesos = 0;
    int tenpesos = 0;
    int fivepesos = 0;
    int onepeso = 0;
    int fiftycentavos = 0;
    int twentyfivecentavos = 0;
    int tencentavos = 0;
    int fivecentavos = 0;
    int onecentavo = 0;

    printf("Welcome to the Alkansiya Calculator!\n");
    printf("How many 1000 pesos?\n"); scanf("%d", &onethousandpesos);
    printf("How many 500 pesos?\n"); scanf("%d", &fivehundredpesos);
    printf("How many 200 pesos?\n"); scanf("%d", &twohundredpesos);
    printf("How many 100 pesos?\n"); scanf("%d", &onehundredpesos);
    printf("How many 50  pesos?\n"); scanf("%d", &fiftypesos);
    printf("How many 20 pesos?\n"); scanf("%d", &twentypesos);
    printf("How many 10 pesos?\n"); scanf("%d", &tenpesos);
    printf("How many 5 pesos?\n"); scanf("%d", &fivepesos);
    printf("How many 1 pesos?\n"); scanf("%d", &onepeso);
    printf("How many 50 cents?\n"); scanf("%d", &fiftycentavos);
    printf("How many 25 cents?\n"); scanf("%d", &twentyfivecentavos);
    printf("How many 10 cents?\n"); scanf("%d", &tencentavos);
    printf("How many 5 cents?\n"); scanf("%d", &fivecentavos);
    printf("How many 1 cents?\n"); scanf("%d", &onecentavo);
    printf("Your balance is %d pesos ", (1000*onethousandpesos)+(500*fivehundredpesos)+(200*twohundredpesos)+(100*onehundredpesos)+(50*fiftypesos)+(20*twentypesos)+(10*tenpesos)+(5*fivepesos)+onepeso);
    printf("and '''%d''' centavos.\n", fiftycentavos+twentyfivecentavos+tencentavos+fivecentavos+onecentavo);
    return 0; 
}
```